# How to make the pagination class in Codeigniter work with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I have a table loaded via AJAX and along with the table the pagination is also loaded through AJAX. The table contains a list of all users on my site limited to 30 at a time.

This is how I'm returning the response to the JavaScript from the controller:

```
    $users = $this->users_m->get_users($type, $offset);
    $num_rows = $this->users_m->user_stats($type);

    $config['per_page'] = 30;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows[0];
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    echo json_encode(array(
        'users' => $users,
        'pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links()
    ));
```

All is well except the pagination is never correct. The first time it is but on subsequent requests it is not.

When using the pagination class in a non AJAX page, the page number I click becomes the active one. Here page 1 is always active (surrounded by `<strong>` tags as opposed to being a link). Secondly the numbers never change. I get:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [>] [Last >]
```

every time. Even if I click last I get the same numbers back, it doesn't change.

How to get the pagination class to work with AJAX?

Comment: the pagination class in CI is using prototype library, have u added that

Comment: Have you tried passing the `base_url` into the initialization function?

Comment: @M Zubair No I'm using jQuery. Anyway the problem isn't on the javascript side. The pagination html that is returned in itself is incorrect. I think it has to do with the pagination class determining which links to show and which one is active based on the url and with AJAX the url never changes.

Comment: yes the pagination html was missing > in the pagination class, thats why I pasted the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I came up with a working solution that I will post here in case anyone else has the same issue.

I used the pagination class found here:

<strike>http://www.catchmyfame.com/2007/07/28/finally-the-simple-pagination-class/</strike>
https://github.com/catchmyfame/PHP-Pagination-Class/blob/master/paginator.class.php

but modified it to work both as a CI library and also with my particular javascript. Create a new file called

`Pagination_ajax.php`

and put it in the same location as the default pagination class in

`/system/libraries`.

This is the modified class:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
 * PHP Pagination Class
 * @author admin@catchmyfame.com - http://www.catchmyfame.com
 * @version 2.0.0
 * @date October 18, 2011
 * @copyright (c) admin@catchmyfame.com (www.catchmyfame.com)
 * @license CC Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-SA 3.0) - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
 */

class Pagination_ajax {
    
    var $items_per_page;
    var $items_total;
    var $current_page;
    var $num_pages;
    var $mid_range;
    var $low;
    var $limit;
    var $return;
    var $default_ipp;
    var $querystring;
    var $ipp_array;

    function Paginator()
    {
        $this->current_page = 1;
        $this->mid_range = 7;
        $this->ipp_array = array(10,25,50,100,'All');
        $this->items_per_page = (!empty($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;
    }

    function paginate()
    {
        if(!isset($this->default_ipp)) $this->default_ipp=25;
        if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
        {
            $this->num_pages = 1;
//          $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
            $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
        }
        $this->current_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ; // must be numeric > 0
        $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
        $next_page = $this->current_page+1;
        if($_GET)
        {
            $args = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
            foreach($args as $arg)
            {
                $keyval = explode("=",$arg);
                if($keyval[0] != "page" And $keyval[0] != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&" . $arg;
            }
        }

        if($_POST)
        {
            foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
            {
                if($key != "page" And $key != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&$key=$val";
            }
        }
        if($this->num_pages > 10)
        {
            $this->return = ($this->current_page > 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a data-page=\"$prev_page\" class=\"paginate\" href=\"#\">&laquo; Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&laquo; Previous</span> ";

            $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
            $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

            if($this->start_range <= 0)
            {
                $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
                $this->start_range = 1;
            }
            if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)
            {
                $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
                $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
            }
            $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
                // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
                if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))
                {
                    $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a data-page=\"$i\" class=\"paginate\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ";
                }
                if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
            }
            $this->return .= (($this->current_page < $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All') And $this->current_page > 0) ? "<a data-page=\"$next_page\" class=\"paginate\" href=\"#\">Next &raquo;</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&raquo; Next</span>\n";
            $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a data-page=\"1\" data-all=\"true\" class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n";
        }
        else
        {
            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
            {
                $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a data-page=\"$i\" class=\"paginate\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ";
            }
            $this->return .= "<a data-page=\"1\" data-all=\"true\" class=\"paginate\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n";
        }
        $this->low = ($this->current_page <= 0) ? 0:($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
        if($this->current_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = 0;
        $this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";
    }
    function display_items_per_page()
    {
        $items = '';
        if(!isset($_GET[ipp])) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        foreach($this->ipp_array as $ipp_opt) $items .= ($ipp_opt == $this->items_per_page) ? "<option selected value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n":"<option value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n";
        return "<span class=\"paginate\">Items per page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'$this->querystring';return false\">$items</select>\n";
    }
    function display_jump_menu()
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            $option .= ($i==$this->current_page) ? "<option value=\"$i\" selected>$i</option>\n":"<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
        }
        return "<span class=\"paginate\">Page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring';return false\">$option</select>\n";
    }
    function display_pages()
    {
        return $this->return;
    }
}
```

You can do a diff between this and the original download to see exactly what I changed.

**Controller code:**

```
    public function get_users() {

        // pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination_ajax');
        $pages = new Pagination_ajax;
        $num_rows = $this->users_m->user_stats(); // this is the COUNT(*) query that gets the total record count from the table you are querying
        $pages->items_total = $num_rows[0];
        $pages->mid_range = 10; // number of links you want to show in the pagination before the "..."
        $pages->paginate();

        $users = $this->users_m->get_users($pages->limit); // your query

        echo json_encode(array(
            'users' => $users,
            'pagination' => $pages->display_pages()
        ));

    }
```

**Model Code:**

```
public function get_users($limit) {

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM `users`
            $limit";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $users = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $users[] = array(
            'user_id'   => $row->user_id,
            'username'  => $row->username,
            'email'     => $row->email
        );
    }

    return $users;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
// pagination
$('#pagination a').live('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var page = $this.data('page');
    var ipp = ($this.data('all')) ? 'All' : 30; // I am returning 30 results per page, change to what you want

    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/users/get_users?page=' + page + '&ipp=' + ipp,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            for(var i=0; i<response.users.length; i++) {
                var user = response.users[i];
                var tr = '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + user.user_id + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + user.username + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + user.email + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';

                $('table tbody').append(tr);
            }

            // pagination
            $('#pagination').html(response.pagination);             
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('An error occurred');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <h1>Users</h1>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>                        
    
    <div id="pagination"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pagination { overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; }
#pagination a { display: inline-block; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 14px; color: #333; border-radius: 3px; text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;  border: 1px solid #ccc;

    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );
}
#pagination a:hover { border: 1px solid #333; }
#pagination a.current { color: #f00; }
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: If we use it with codeignitor how could GET work ? I see there are manu instances of $_GET ? I am facing this problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in this way, add jquery library

pagination class:

```
 $html = "<a style=\"cursor:pointer\"  onclick=\"pagination('$url','$par','$div')\" >$text</a>";
        else:
        $html = "<a style=\"cursor:pointer\" onclick=\"pagination('$url','','$div')\" >$text</a>";
```

JS

```
var ServerCall = function(_url,_data,callback){

    $('#Spinner').center().show();
    _data = (_data == null)?'':_data;
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: _url,
           data: 'ajax=1&'+_data,
           dataType:'html',
           success: 
             function(result) {
             $('#Spinner').hide();
                callback(result);
           },
            error: function (data, status, e){
                $('#Spinner').hide();
            }
        });
};


var pagination = function (_url,_params,_div)
{
    ServerCall(_url,_params,function(data){

        $('#'+_div).html(data);
        $('.editTableRow').bind('click',editfunction);
    });
};
```