# Error in ajax jquery pagination in CI

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

Got error in jquery pagination in codeigniter.

```
    if per_page=5;
    total number 6 and total page 2

    but the pagination like below

    Showing 6 to 6 of 6 |  < 1 2
    But only 5 is shown and last one show in 2nd page.
```

Hi friends i am stuck in this bug.This show in every pages.Pls give me a solution to get correct pagination

below code is using:

```
            $config['base_url'] = site_url('settings/view_leave_reason_ajax/');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->leav->getLvReasonCount();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;        
        $config['anchor_class'] = 'ajax_links';
        $config['show_count'] = true;
        $config['div'] = '#list_view';
        $this->jquery_pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data["links"] = $this->jquery_pagination->create_links();
        $data['page'] = $page;
        $data['result'] = $this->leav->getLvReason($config["per_page"], $page);
```

question regarding the below ci pagination:

https://github.com/neotohin/CodeIgniter-Ajax-pagination-Library

view page:

```
<?php if($result=="")
                {?>
                <tr style="height: 50px; background:#ffffff; font-weight: bold;">
                    <td colspan="5" style="width:50px;">
                        No Details Exist
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                if($result!="")
                {
                $c = $page+1;
                $col1[1]="";
                $col1[2]="#d6e3f6";
                $col=$col1[2];
                    foreach ($result as $row)
                    {
                        $did = $row['id'];
                ?>
                <tr style="height: 50px;background:<?php echo $col;?>;">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="c1[]"  value="<?php echo $did;?>" /></td>
                    <td><?php echo $c;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['department_name'];?></td>
                    <td>

                            <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="<?php echo site_url()."/settings/department_edit/".$this->hrm->encData($row['id']); ?>" ><img class="aicon" src="<?php echo base_url().'/assets/images/edit.png';?>" width="20" title="edit" style="margin-top:4px; margin-left:3px;"></a>
                    </td>   
                </tr>
                <?php  $c=$c+1;
                if($col == $col1[1])    $col = $col1[2];
                else $col = $col1[1];
                    }

                ?>
                <tr style="height: 50px; background:#ffffff; font-weight: bold;">
                    <td colspan="5" style="width:50px;">
                        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn_black" onclick="return chkdel()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php }?>

                <tr  style="height: 50px;"><td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; padding-right:10px;"><?php echo $links; ?></td></tr>
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384835/how-to-make-the-pagination-class-in-codeigniter-work-with-ajax?rq=1

Comment: this is a bug regarding ci pagination: https://github.com/neotohin/CodeIgniter-Ajax-pagination-Library         also it is reported as an issue there....

Comment: Try setting the proper uri_segment in config, the default uri segment is 3

Comment: would you give me the "view" file ?

Comment: @fawwaz view page is with question now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined

```
 $config['div'] = '#list_view';
```

in your config, but you haven't defined that container in your view. Hence no ajax calls will be sent.

So instead of this

```
<tr  style="height: 50px;"><td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; padding-right:10px;"><?php echo $links; ?></td></tr>
```

Try putting the container `<div id="list_view"><?php echo $links; ?></div>` as below:

```
<tr  style="height: 50px;"><td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; padding-right:10px;"><div id="list_view"><?php echo $links; ?></div></td></tr>
```

Also in the pagination library  `Jquery_pagination.php`

change this line at `line number 184` from

```
if( ( $curr_offset + $this->per_page ) < ( $this->total_rows -1 ) )
```

to

```
if( ( $curr_offset + $this->per_page ) <= ( $this->total_rows -1 ) )
```

And it will be working...

Comment: i cannot find code for the model function `getLvReason` in your question

Comment: Hi have found the bug. PLease check the answer

Comment: no need the change with <div>.Change in jquery_pagination is working properly

Comment: i didn't see any container that's why posted it.